# Приоритет intent-filter

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Задача у меня следующая: написать свой экран для ответа на звонок.

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        Intent intentCall = new Intent("android.intent.action.ANSWER");
        intentCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intentCall);
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.al_3_broadcast_receiver"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CallActivity">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".CallBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Собственно мой CallActivity вызывается но после стандартного экрана. Как сделать чтобы мой запускался раньше?

Comment: priority="99999" поставь еще выше

Comment: не помогло

Comment: Почитайте [здесь][1]. Пишут, что нужно перед запуском Activity задержку миллисекунд в 100 выставить.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869314/can-an-activity-receive-an-unordered-broadcastincoming-call-intent-before-syst

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно помню, то перехват телефонного вызова в Android'е с заменой дефолтного приложения невозможен.

Здесь все дело в том, что входящий вызов не относится к ordered broadcast, то есть бродкаст неупорядочен (non-ordered) и распространяется всем интентам одновременно. Скажем, бродкаст о входящем СМС относится к ordered broadcast и соответственно есть возможность перехвата через выставление приоритета с запретом дальнейшей обработки через `abortBroadcast()` и т.д., а в non-ordered broadcast приоритет роли не играет.

> - Normal broadcasts (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely
>   asynchronous. All receivers of the
>   broadcast are run in an undefined
>   order, often at the same time. This is
>   more efficient, but means that
>   receivers cannot use the result or
>   abort APIs included here.
> - Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are
>   delivered to one receiver at a time.
>   As each receiver executes in turn, it
>   can propagate a result to the next
>   receiver, or it can completely abort
>   the broadcast so that it won't be
>   passed to other receivers. The order
>   receivers run in can be controlled
>   with the android:priority attribute of
>   the matching intent-filter; receivers
>   with the same priority will be run in
>   an arbitrary order.

[Читать здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)